# Python how to derive complete hierarchy from an entity-relationship structure

Tags: python

I have a dictionary which contains Entity Relationship of few tables, I need a list containing complete hierarchy of the nodes.

```
{
  'a': {
    'b': ['key11', 'key21'],
    'c': ['key12', 'key22']
  },
  'b': {
    'd': ['key13', 'key23'],
    'e': ['key14', 'key24']
  },
  'c': {
    'f': ['key15', 'key25']
  }
}
```

where in -

- a,b,c,d,e,f are table names
- *a* is a parent table and *b* and *c* are child tables and the corresponding list defines the keys that both the tables join on. e.g. *key11* of table *a* is related to *key21* of table *b*.
- Similarly, *d* and *e* are child tables of table *b* and so on and so forth.

I need to connect all the nodes from root to leaf to have a complete hierarchy like the below:

```
[
  ['a', 'b', 'd']
  ['a', 'b', 'e']
  ['a', 'c', 'f']
]
```

My solution is half baked and I don't know how to proceed further.

```
def connect_by_root(ele: str, er_data: dict, _tree: list = []) -> list:
    """
    Identify dependent tables using recursion
    """

    if ele in er_data:
        if not _tree:
            _tree.append(ele)
        for k in er_data[ele].keys():
            _tree.append(k)
            return connect_by_root(k, er_data, _tree)
    else:
        return _tree
        
tree = connect_by_root('a', d, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an elegant one, but it works and can be applied for any level of nesting

```
def connect_by_root(ele: str, er_data: dict, lst: list = [], _tree=[], root=None) -> list:
    """
    Identify dependent tables using recursion
    """

    if root == None:    
        root = ele

    if ele in er_data:
        if not ele in lst:
            lst.append(ele)
        for k in er_data[ele].keys():
            lst.append(k)
            connect_by_root(k, er_data, lst, _tree, root)
            if not isinstance(er_data[ele][k], dict):
                if not lst in _tree:
                    if not root in lst:
                        lst.insert(0, root)
                    _tree.append(lst)
                    lst = [ele]
                else:
                    lst = [ele]

    return(_tree)


my_dict = {
          'a': {
            'b': ['key11', 'key21'],
            'c': ['key12', 'key22']
          },
          'b': {
            'd': ['key13', 'key23'],
            'e': ['key14', 'key24']
          },
          'c': {
            'f': ['key15', 'key25']
          },
          'f': {
            'h': ['key16', 'key26']
          }
        }


tree = connect_by_root('a', my_dict, [], [])

print(tree)
```

Result:

```
[['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'e'], ['a', 'c', 'f', 'h']]
```

Comment: This would do. Thanks :)